# Wordpress: Echo PHP depending on page ID

Tags: php, wordpress, posts

Good afternoon, I'm trying to display posts using PHP in the template, but I'm using the same template to output different posts depending on the age ID.

I currently have this code which works...

```
<?php //GET MEMBERS ?>
                    <?php query_posts('category_name=members&orderby=date'); ?>
                    <div class="row-fluid">
                        <ul class="thumbnails">
                            <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
                            <li class="span4">
                                <div class="thumbnail">
                                    <?php // check if the post has a Post Thumbnail assigned to it.
                                    the_post_thumbnail();
                                    ?>
                                    <div class="pad">
                                        <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
                                        <?php the_content(); ?>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                            <?php endwhile; ?>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <?php endif; ?>
```

But I need to output a different "category" depending on page ID... E.G

if page id is 7 echo "php script"
else page id is 13 echo "different php script"

Thanks, Brad

Answer (score 1):

Wordpress has some built in functions. You can use `get_the_ID()` to return the ID number to use in your if statements.

Regards